# Add class to a child element on scroll (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having trouble with jQuery and JS in general.  How do I add a class to a child element on vertical scroll in order to animate it?

Ex:

```
    <div class="wrapper">
      <p> Lorem ipsum </p>
    </div>

    $(window).scroll(function(){
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

      if(scroll <= 770) {
        $('.wrapper p').addClass('animate fadeInDownBig');

      }
   });
```

I just wanna addClass to the paragraph. Not the wrapper.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet, or are you just throwing your hands in the air and giving up?

Comment: On scroll of what...? window? wrap..?

Comment: Oops will jFiddle this instead

Comment: Do you wanna use jQuery or just JavaScript? You can't be so broad. Should we answer the question twice, using each?

Comment: @OlegDeLeon You have to put relevant code in question, not just linking to a jsFiddle

Comment: Edited my question. Please check if this makes sense.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/mawob/1/edit demo

Answer (score 0):

As per your recent edit:

```
 $(window).scroll(function(){
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
      if(scroll <= 770) {
        $('.wrapper').find("p").addClass('animate fadeInDownBig');
      }
   });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/mawob/1/edit)**